# Read json file to search key value in python

Tags: python, json

I am using python 3.4.3 and trying to read the following structure from a file

```
[ 
{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Ã…land Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
{"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}
]
```

My code is a follows

```
>>> import json
>>> data = open("c:/iq/data/country.json","r").read()
>>> test = json.load(data)

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    test = json.load(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'*
```

Then I would have used something like

```
 for key,value in test.items():
    print(key,value)
```

But I can not seem to go past the load error, printed above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that `open().read()` returns a string, but `json.load` takes a "file-like object" (See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).) If you have the file in a string like this, you want `json.loads`:

```
data = open("c:/iq/data/country.json","r").read()
test = json.loads(data)
```

But since you want to read from a file, you can use `json.load`, you just have to give it a file rather than a string:

```
with open("c:/iq/data/country.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

If you want, you can verify this with `pprint`:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data_str = open("c:/iq/data/country.json", "r").read()
data = json.loads(data_str)
pprint(data)

with open("c:/iq/data/country.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  bytesized.  Yours is a lot better solution then how I got it to work.  I was able to read with load with a str conversion such as  data= json.loads(str(file))

Comment: @iq_av I'm glad I could help! If this answers your question, you should mark the answer as accepted.